# Why can the droids pass through the Gungans' shields but their weapons can't?

Tags: star-wars

Why is it that shields stop the droid army's weapons but the droids themselves can pass through the shields without any problems? Would they have been able to attack the Gungans if they had something other than energy weapons, maybe something physical such as bullets or cannon balls?

Comment: I'm assuming it also applies to Anakin passing through the shields of the command ship. Do shields just prevent energy weapons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, the shields they used would only block things with at least a certain threshold of energy or speed.

From the [Wookieepedia entry on shields](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Deflector_shield):

> The Gungan shields used during the Battle of Naboo blocked lasers, but droids could pass through because of their relatively slow movement in comparison to the laser bolts.

Comment: "The shield turns the fast blow, admits the slow kindjal!"

Comment: Sounds like the Goa'uld personal shields on Stargate SG1. Hmm...

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I came across a source that discussed this. From the Episode I novelization:

> The Gungan shield wall was designed to deflect large, slow-moving objects of density and mass such as artillery vehicles and small, fast-moving objects generating extreme heat such as projectiles from weapons fire. But it would not deflect small, slow-moving droids.